# Paho: MqttAsyncClient.getInFlightMessageCount() is sometimes over 100

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am using the the version `1.2.5` of the `mqtt5 paho java Client` and sending Messages with `QoS1` - the `inflight` message count is normally a low single digit. Is that more a problem of the client or the `Broker`(using mosquitto) not able to manage the workload?

the `mosquitto.conf` looks like that

```
max_inflight_bytes 0
max_inflight_messages 0
retain_available true
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
allow_anonymous true
```

sometimes the `publish` method, altough I am using the `async`-Client, is blocking for seconds or in rare case even over a minute.

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem? How big are the messages? what is the message rate? Without a MRT of the code in question it's hard to say more.

Comment: @hardillb in this scenario it is like 10msg every 100-150ms. The messages is quite short(abt 10bytes) but there are a few userProperties(abt 50byte) I send too.

Comment: How many subscribers? One thing to remember, mosquitto is a single threaded event loop, so for every inbound message it needs to send N times that much data out for N subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Since QOS 1 is a 2 step process

1. Client sends message to the broker
2. Broker sends acknowledgement it's received the message

A growing number of inflight messages would imply that it's the broker that is being slow to respond.

With the information available in the question that is probably about the only answer possible to give.